# Geometry Nodes point grid boolean subtraction?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So i need to subtract the intersected part of the cubed points from the other, i was thinking maybe a vector distance calculation, to calculate the shortest vector length between each point and maybe use a compare node, but i am really new to this and would appreciate someone to show me how its done, thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2):

> ...I was thinking maybe a vector distance calculation, to calculate the shortest vector length between each point and maybe use a compare node...

I think you're heading in the right direction with that idea, here are some pointers to help you achieve the rest of the solution.

For this case, using **Geometry Proximity** node will be an ideal approach since your goal is to find the intersected parts where the points on the two Cube objects meet (the area where the points are closets to each other -> they'll have the shortest distance). **Geometry Proximity** will do this automatically for you (it'll find the closet point on the targeted object, calculate the distance from the original/source points to the points on the targeted object and give you an distance output to use)

Once you'll get the distance/length between every two points that are on both of your Cube point objects, you can start to use the **Compare** node to separate non-intersected and intersected part from the original geometry.

The result:

*Points that have smaller radius indicate the intersected section.*
[image]

*The intersected section.*
[image]

*The non-intersected section.*
[image]

Here's the node setup. You can also throw in another custom node group that shows different parts of your geometry: Original - Non-Intersected - Intersected which can come in handy later on in case you still want to reuse it.
[image]

I also attached the blend file in case you want to examine it yourself later on.

[image]

Comment: thank you, i found this very helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

You may as well solve this by creating a convex hull around one cube and check for each point of the other cube, if it is within the convex hull by using raycasts.

[image: node net]

[image: cubes]
[image: cube1 without cube2]
[image: cube2 without cube 1]

And this is, how the Is Point in Object node looks like:

[image: Is Point in Object node]

I already described this node here: [How can you fill one mesh's volume with as many of another mesh that will fit?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258583/how-can-you-fill-one-meshs-volume-with-as-many-of-another-mesh-that-will-fit)

[image]