# Remove sections of a point cloud with Geometry Proximity or any other node setup

Tags: geometry-nodes, point-clouds

I am trying to create slits in this point cloud model (.ply filetype). The geometry I would like to use to delete the slits in the point cloud is a plane with an array modifier (to control the distance between each slit) and a solidify modifier to change the thickness of each slit. I am not very experienced with *Geometry Proximity* or *Delete Geometry* nodes so I have tried to use a *Delete Geometry* but it just deletes a random portion of the point cloud. Can anyone help with a node setup? I can share the blend file if required.

Here is the current node setup but it does not seem to be deleting as per the geometry of the plane (with modifier stack):

[image: The current node setup]

Array geometry used to delete geometry:

[image: array geometry used to delete geometry]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtjGG.jpg - Image shows the plane I would like to use to delete sections of the point cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look onto your model, there are two points to be mentioned:

- My other answer requires a mesh as input geometry. You already start with only vertices. That's why my other solution does not work for you.
- You did not apply all transforms on your point-cloud object. That's why it would not have even worked, if it were a mesh.

But luckily there is a way to solve it:

- First you have to apply all transforms on the point-cloud object.
- Then I created a group node, which I already explained in this ([How can you fill one mesh's volume with as many of another mesh that will fit?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258583/how-can-you-fill-one-meshs-volume-with-as-many-of-another-mesh-that-will-fit)) thread. This node can check, if a position is whithin another object. This leads you to the following solution:

[image: node setup]

The "Is Point in Object" node:
[image: "Is Point in Object" node]

And so does it look like:
[image: rendered result]

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @AndreZmuda. You are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

When your geometry is a mesh, you could do it, using the *Mesh Boolean* Node like this:

[image: Node Setup]

And so does it look like, when beeing applied to an icosphere:

[image: Icosphere with plane stack]

[image: Icosphere with deleted points]

Comment: I have tried this already and it just deletes the whole point cloud. I can send you the blend file if you would like to try?

Comment: @CaileanBochMurphy, yes, sure, I can give it a try.

Comment: great that you. Whats the best way to get it to you?

Comment: @CaileanBochMurphy, best would be, to upload it on https://blend-exchange.com/ and post the link right here

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BJNO5Psq" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BJNO5Psq/)

Comment: @CaileanBochMurphy, I solved it and placed it in a new answer. Nevertheless, I will keep this answer, as it might help others, who start with a mesh.